# Computing Average In MM:SS in excel

Tags: excel

Input: Minutes:Seconds
Output: Average in Minutes:Seconds

I currently have a sheet where we put in handle times for calls. We want to compute the average handling time in minutes:seconds. Now, currently we have minutes in Column A and seconds in Column B. In Column C, I convert A&B to total seconds. In Column D, I use =AVERAGE(C1:C6) to compute for average.

Question: Do we have an easier way to doit? Specifically, is there any formula that will allow me to simply input Minutes:Seconds in a single column and have the average in Minutes:Seconds to be calculated?

Comment: how about some sample data and what you would expect to see, please ?

Comment: I just tried a test: if column A has "time" entered in format: "MM:SS", then you can just use: `=average(A:A)` ... it seems to handle it fine ?? Have you tried running AVERAGE on your "MM:SS" format ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Option 1:

*(If you can change your input format):*

You need to set the data format as hh:mm:ss 
Inputting the data in this format will allow excel to automatically detect the format and as such, allow for you to use the 'average' formula. 
For example, if you have 3 entries for: 2 minutes, 1 min 30 secs and 1 minute, the data in col A should look like:

```
00:02:00
00:01:30
00:01:00
```

You can then run, for example, the formula:

```
=AVERAGE(A1:A3)
```

Note: By default, putting the data in the format "xx:yy", excel will assume that xx is the hours and yy is the minutes, so you should pass the initial 00: if you don't have your time in hours

#### Option 2:

*(If you cannot change your input format):*

If you need to stick to the format where col A contains the minutes and col b contains the seconds, you can use the following formula to pass "hh:mm:ss" data in col c:

```
=(A1/(24*60))+(B1/(24*60*60))
```

(default date value is set to '1 day' for a cell, so we divide by 24 hrs and 60 mins to convert it to 'minutes' from col A and 24*60*60 to get seconds from col B) 
You can then use a folmula similar to the one below to calculate the average time in col C:

```
=AVERAGE(C1:C3)
```

Note: You would need to set column C to the 'Custom format':

```
hh:mm:ss
```